# Facebook lint says it can't read my site?

Tags: facebook, lint

When using the facebook linter, I give it the root URL of my site - http://www.rockyhorror.org and ask it to do its thing. It reports

Errors That Must Be Fixed
Can't Download  Could not retrieve data from URL.

Yet when I created a new page, http://www.rockyhorror.org/fblint.html as a copy of the source, it works great. The only changes I made to the static page (fblint.html) was to change the base and the URL so that it pointed to itself and not the root url as the copy from "view source" provided.

That passes the linter without problem. It'll give me the source when I click the "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" link, whereas when I click that link on the erroring usage, I get nothing.

Can anyone see what might be wrong?! I'm at wit's end here. I can't see a problem at all, and the fact that I can copy the source and it works makes absolutely no sense to me.

Is there a chance that the error means literally what it says, and Facebook can't physically connect or read from my root URL? If so, why can it get the static page? And if this is the case, why not an error message that's more descriptive? The error I'm getting tells me *nothing* about what is broken or what to fix.

Anyone have any adult supervision?

Comment: Check your web server access logs and error logs for relevant information.

Comment: There are no entries in any of my logs that give useful information. If I tail -f my access.log and then hit the Facebook linter, I get this log entry:

69.171.234.119 - - [08/Dec/2013:19:01:49 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13146 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"

A nice 200 response and 13146 bytes of fine, hand-crafted HTML given to Facebook for their pleasure.